# My zte ac 8700 usb modem is not recognized. What should I do?

Tags: drivers, usb, wubi, modem, support

I am a new user to Ubuntu.
I have seen Ubuntu on Youtube got attracted, so I installed it on my Acer Aspire One Happy 2 Netbook as a software in win 7 starter.

Everything is good, but when comes to the Internet connection, I am facing a severe problem, in that my Ubuntu is not recognising or supporting the USB modem (provided by zte ac 8700 model of bsnl in India). Can any one tell me what to do? I have searched in some sites, and all are providing codes.

I am just beginner and not a technical person, so help me in a way that I can understand.

Comment: (it's roland) :)

Answer (score 1):

[This seems to be a pretty solid howto](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1719649):

> After Long hours of hard work, I finally found out how to connect ZTE EV-DO AC8700 USB Modem supplied by BSNL, India. Here's what I did and what's to be done:-
>
> 1. Download the linux driver for ZTE EV-DO AC8700 from http://www.ztemt.com/ennewzte/uploadimages/1257081294661.zip
> 2. Extract it and then install the .deb package/app (CrossPlatformUI-V1.0.27-BSNL-i386-ubuntu.deb).
> 3. Install GNOME PPP (gnome dial up tool). This can be found from [ Applications - Ubuntu Software Centre and in search bar type GNOME PPP]. Obviously, you'll need Internet Connection for this download.
> 4. Now, u'll find the application (ZTEMT UI) in [Applications-Internet-ZTEMT UI].
> 5. Open it. Click Settings. Input phone number as #777,Username and then password. Click Connect and then Voila!!! Happy Now ?